# Entity framework - how to avoid commands out of sync exception

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I wrote a small application using entity framework (`DbContext`), UnitOfWork and repository patterns. the following code

```
using (IUnitOfWork testUow = uowFactory.CreateUnitOfWork())
{
    foreach (Transponder transp in testUow.Transponders.GetAll()) // outer sql
    {
        var query = testUow.Animals.GetAll()
                    .Where(anim => anim.TransponderId == transp.Id); // inner sql

        // next line throws EntityCommandException: 
        Animal test = query.Single(); 
    }
}
```

produces an

`EntityCommandException: {"Commands out of sync;  You can't run this command now"}`

`Transponders` and `Animals` are my repositories.

**Why do I get this exception?**

Isn't it ok to have code that produces nested sql commands like in my example (marked as inner and outer sql in code example).

**How can I change my code/design to avoid this exception?**

I know I can rewrite the linq query, so it is a one liner that works, but I'm interested in more general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql (connector) doesn't support multiple active result sets (MARS). So while executing the outer query (which runs while the loop iterates) it can't read other result sets over the same connection.

So, as you say, rewriting the query is the solution. It's better anyway, because you've got a 1+N problem here.

Comment: So the design per se is correct, I simply have to avoid MARS? But if my unit of work has a long life time (like shared life time with the view model), there will be many many queries on the same connection. How can I avoid MARS then?

Comment: Could you explain what's a 1+N problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: N + 1 is the anti-pattern where 1 query triggers N queries to fetch related objects, while a join could get all in one query. The usually call it N + 1, not 1+N, don't know why actually. As for the MARS issue, I think you should avoid lazy loading, because that triggers queries while the owning objects are read. But in general it's a good idea to reduce the lifespan of your contexts.